# How to pass values as parameters to a function call inside onclick in Angular2 without ngClick?

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular2: I am trying to pass values from an `*ngFor` loop as a parameter to function call on the `(click)` attribute *(since calling functions on onclick is not allowed for security reasons)* event on my anchor tag.

Template Code:

```
<div *ngFor='let artist of artists'>
   <a (click)="alert({{artist.artist_id}})" href="#">{{artist.artist_name}}</a>
</div>
```

Compile Time error:

```
Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected in [alert({{artist.artist_id}})]
```

Problem:

How do I pass the value of artist to the function call on `(click)`?

*Any/All help appreciated! :)*

Comment: Never use `()` or `[]` together with `{{}}`. Either one or the other but not together. (`()` and `[]` can be used together).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you for that pointer! `()` and `[]` together always remind me of the sweet `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: Yup, called banana-in-a box, in case you want to know :D - to not mix it up with box-in-a-banana which is invalid ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case, you don't need the double-curly braces since you are passing the variable to a function in a event binding click attribute, therefore you can remove those braces and it will work as expected:

```
<div *ngFor='let artist of artists'>
   <a (click)="alert(artist.artist_id)" href="#">{{artist.artist_name}}</a>
</div>
```

According to the [relevant documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#interpolation), you only need to use interpolation when inserting a value between HTML element tags and within attribute assignments (not to be confused with event/property binding).

For instance, you would need to use interpolation for this direct `src` attribute assignment, otherwise the value would be interpreted as a string:

```
<img src="{{pathUrl}}" />
```

However, if you were to use [property binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding) (i.e., `[src]` rather than `src`), it would be treated as a variable and the interpolation wouldn't be required:

```
<img [src]="pathUrl" />
```

The same would apply to [event binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding) like in your case.

In other words, as stated by [Günter in the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943673/how-to-pass-values-as-parameters-to-a-function-call-inside-onclick-in-angular2-w/41943697#comment71067715_41943673), you never need to use event/property binding, (i.e., `()`/`[]`/`[()]`), together with variable interpolation, (i.e., double-curly braces, `{{}}`).

Comment: Worked like a charm @Josh ! Thank you so much! Cheers. Happy Coding <3

Comment: Thanks so much.. Saved my day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simply by removing the interpolation and calling the `alert(artist.artist_id)`